# Using Python, how can I groupby and get values of all rows that meet criteria, excluding current row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a Pandas dataframe containing 2 columns, both with continuous integers. On a row-by-row basis, by grouping all equal values in col_1, i am trying to create lists of all values in col_2, excluding the row in question and store this in a new column (col_3). Full example below:

Current dataframe:

```
col_1       col_2
24          30  
24          22  
24          34  
40          50
```

Required dataframe:

```
col_1       col_2       col_3
24          30          [22,34]
24          22          [30,34]
24          34          [30,22]
40          50          []
```

I have tried groupby, but this is including the 'current' row and its values, which i need to exclude.

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1' : [24,24,24,40], 'col_2' : [30,22,34,50}, index=range(4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest approach to this is to simply remove the current row value from column 3. Depending on how you did this you might be able to do this on your creation of column 3 or you can apply a function to remove the first value the matches the current row value (i.e. be careful not to remove all instances of the current value in case there are more than one). If you need more assistance I can follow up but I think you've got it since you already almost have it.

Edit:

1. Create column 3 like you already did
2. define function to apply to dataframe, then apply the function

## starting from df with column 3

def remove_col2_val(row):
if row[3]:
row[3].remove(row[2])
return row

df = df.apply(remove_col2_val, axis=1)

If there was a chance the row[2] value was not in the list (shouldn't be the case here but for future reference) then you would want to wrap the row[3].remove(row[2]) in a try/except block.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What would you recommend the most efficient code is for doing that? Currently, my only solution is to create a copy of the dataframe, delete the row i am working on, filter the copied dataframe for col_1 criteria and then transfer this to the original dataframe. This is not an efficient method and i am trying to improve it.

Comment: Noticed you had an empty list in your example so edited again.

Comment: apologies, I'm not sure what's wrong with the code formatting in the response. Hope you're able to break that down. the function is just checking for a truth statement (i.e. no empty list in this case). If the list is not empty, remove the current row[2] value. You may want to wrap the .remove() in a try/except if there is a chance that the row[2] value is not in the list when it's not empty. Make sure the function always returns the row.